# How to distinguish between ContentDocument and ContentNote?

Tags: contentdocument, sobjecttype, contentdocumentlink, contentnote

There seems to be some unusual stuff going on with `SObjectType` for the [enhanced note](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Consideration-for-enhanced-notes-and-using-Files&language=en_US&type=1) `ContentNote` ([ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm)) object and the underling `ContentDocument` ([ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm)) structure.

For example, both these return a single row (with the Id taken from an enhanced note I created);

```
select Id from ContentDocument where Id = '069R00000002J0m'
select Id from ContentNote where Id = '069R00000002J0m'
```

and these both return "069":

```
System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ContentDocument').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ContentNote').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
```

and this:

```
System.debug(((Id) '069R00000002J0m').getSObjectType());
```

outputs `ContentDocument`.

This turns out to be quite awkward for a change to some existing code that I am making, in that AFAIK the only way to generically identify an enhanced note versus a File attachment is to check that the `ContentDocument.FileType` has the value "SNOTE". As far as triggers and `SObjectType` based logic is concerned, `ContentDocument` is the type.

Please share any **insight you may have on what is going on here** so that I make my code changes in the cleanest way.

Comment: Did you ever gain any more insight into what is happening here? Trying to put a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` that only does something if it is tied to a ContentNote. I would prefer to not do the answer below even though it will work.

Comment: Hi @JesseMilburn, Sorry at this point this has faded into a blurred (unpleasant) memory...

Comment: Totally understandable. I'll just query the parents and check for FileType = 'SNOTE'. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: what does 'SNOTE' indicate?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana A rich (HTML) text note as far as I recall.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC. Is there a list of possible values for this field? I did a describe on the field and it's a text field (not a picklist)

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana Likely to be a [mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types). Attach a file and then query in the developer console to check the field value. Post a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

ContentDocument contains more fields than ContentNote,  ContentDocument will always have LatestPublishedVersionId (As it junction to contentVersion), probably you can use that to your advantage?

```
if(rec.get('LatestPublishedVersionId')==null){
   //Its a Note
}else{
  //Its content document.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pranay. I think the FileType is probably a better way to go if I have to check fields. Really looking for some explanation of what is going on too.

Answer (score 1):

A `ContentNote` is a `ContentDocument` with a `FileType` of "SNOTE".

If you create a `ContentVersion` record with `PathOnClient` set to `<something>.snote`, you'll see that you can query this note through `ContentNote` as well.

This can be useful if you want to set `FirstPublishLocationId` when inserting your note, i.e. `ContentVersion`, to avoid a separate `ContentDocumentLink` insert, or if you want to add a custom field to your notes, which `ContentVersion` supports.

(To ensure your note content can be saved, set `VersionData` to `myNoteString.escapeUnicode().escapeHtml4()`.)