# DLRS: How to count all Files (without Notes) related to an Opportunity?

Tags: files, contentdocument, roll-up-summary, contentdocumentlink, dlrs

I created a DLRS (Declarative Lookup Roll-up Summary) on the Opportunity that counts how many Files are related to it. However, the count gives me both the Files+Notes and I only want the File count, without Notes. Any idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Example:
The count says 5+1=6. I only need the 5 files.

[image]

I check the object [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) and dont find a way to distinguish between Files and Notes. Any idea?

---

Update:

Using @David Cheng idea I tried to use as the Relationship Criteria ContentDocument.FileType = 'PDF' but it looks like you can not traverse across objects in DLRS.

The query works in Workbench but not in DLRS.

Workbench
SELECT count() FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '0063l00000hLMbhAAG' AND ContentDocument.FileType = 'PDF'

DLRS
[image]

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225908/how-to-distinguish-between-contentdocument-and-contentnote

Comment: You should be able to use standard dot-notation to reference a related `ContentDocument` field in the Relationship Criteria field, e.g. `ContentDocument.FileType != [whatever values ContentNote uses]`.

Comment: @DavidCheng I just tried to add the Relationship Criteria ContentDocument.FileType = 'PDF' but get and error. Looks like you can traverse across objects on DLRS. See my updated question.

Comment: PDF was just an example, you need to determine the correct data type for the FileType field, or use a different field for your criteria.

Comment: I get what you mean, the challenge is not the FileType. ContentDocument.FileType != 'SNOTE' to exclude notes, or ContentDocument.FileType = 'PDF' to only count PDF. The challenge is not been able to query across object on the DLRS Relationship Criteria.

Comment: Unfortunately then you'll have to write your own Apex trigger on `ContentDocumentLink`.

Comment: More specifically, you can't filter on ContentDocumentLink without either providing a list of LinkedEntityIds or a list of ContentDocumentIds (see the error message in your screen shot). This is a limitation of ContentDocumentLink